# Grails Spring Security Openid

Tags: spring, security, grails, openid

I am trying to get the simple tutorial app working with 
Grails 2.3 and spring-security-openid:2.0-RC1

Initially i was not able to to execute the s2-quickstart and after some research , I got to know i first had to compile the project so

after creating the project , moved into the folder and then ran compile ( after i added the plugin lines in the buildconfig.groovy) . Steps i have done in order ..

1. Grails create-app testproject
2. update the buildconfig.groovy to include the plugin
3. cd testproject
4. grails s2-quickstart com.testproject User Role
5. grails s2-init-openid  ----> this does not create the openIDController classes and the gsps

I keep seeing the following 
 Script 'S2InitOpenid' not found, did you mean:
  1) Init
  2) S2CreateOpenid
  3) PluginInfo_
  4) UninstallPlugin
  5) S2CreatePersistentToken
 Please make a selection or enter Q to quit: q

Appreciate any and all help ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run the `s2-init-openid` in the 2.0 version of the plugin, and it has been removed. The files that were copied to your application are now included in the plugin itself.

Just run `s2-quickstart` then `s2-create-openid`, and `s2-create-persistent-token` if you want to support remember-me. This is all described in the docs, which are not available right now due to Github issues but should be online again soon.